# Exportar relatório do ReportViewer para CSV

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

No *ReportViewer* usando *Winforms*, quando crio o relatório só tenho a opção de exportar para PDF, Excel e Word e preciso adicionar a opção de exportar em CSV.

Comment: Não consegui nenhuma dica para o RDL ou RDLC. Já com o Crystal Reports (RPT), o CSV já e uma opção natural para exportação.

Comment: pelo q procurei  na net tbm tive isso de resposta...vlw

Comment: Se você tiver o controle do DataSet pode utilizar isso http://stackoverflow.com/a/8810229/6809703, que seria DataSet->CSV, ou então poderia exportar para Excel para depois transformar em CSV, que da pra fazer tudo programaticamente.

Comment: Pode oferecer mais detalhes, afim de que possa montar um exemplo?

Comment: Usando o Report Server é possível exportar para Excel, MHTML, PDF, TIFF, XML, and CSV. Já o Report  local não permite, o jeito é buscar alternativas conforme colocado pelos outros comentários. Este link mostra como fazer um hack que permite exportar local para MSWord, que não é uma opção nativa para o ReportViewer no windows, o processo é trabalhoso mas talvez você consiga reproduzir para CSV: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23966/Report-Viewer-generate-reports-MS-Word-formats

Comment: pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325592/export-to-csv-in-localreport-of-reportviewer-of-winform

Answer (score -1):

```
private void reportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { var fieldInfo = typeof(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RenderingExtension).GetField("m_isVisible", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

foreach (var extension in this.reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions())
{
    if (string.Compare("EXCELOPENXML", extension.Name) == 0)
        fieldInfo.SetValue(extension, true);
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public override IEnumerable<ExcelExportInfo> ListExcelExportInfo()
{
    if (this.ExportToExcel == null) 
    { 
        List<ExcelExportInfo> list = new List<ExcelExportInfo>(); 

        Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer renderer = new Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer(); 
        list.Add(new ExcelExportInfo("Excel", renderer.LocalizedName, true, typeof(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer), true));

        this.ExportToExcel = list; 
    } 
    return this.ExportToExcel; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Carregue seu relatório no ReportViewer
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "CaminhoDoSeuRelatorio.rdlc";
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void ExportToCsv(string filePath, string content)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, content, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    private void btnExportToCsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Obtém os dados do relatório
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;

        byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "CSV", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

        // Salva o conteúdo CSV em um arquivo
        string filePath = "CaminhoDoArquivo.csv";
        ExportToCsv(filePath, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));

        MessageBox.Show("Exportado para CSV com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo:

btnExportToCsv_Click é o manipulador de evento do botão que aciona a exportação para CSV.
ExportToCsv é uma função auxiliar que escreve o conteúdo CSV em um arquivo.
Certifique-se de substituir "CaminhoDoSeuRelatorio.rdlc" e "CaminhoDoArquivo.csv" pelos caminhos corretos do seu relatório e do local onde você deseja salvar o arquivo CSV.

Note que este é apenas um exemplo básico, e a geração de CSV pode variar dependendo da estrutura do seu relatório. Certifique-se de ajustar o código conforme necessário para atender às suas necessidades específicas.

Comment: Parece que o [LocalReport não renderiza CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms252172(v=vs.100)) e que os formatos suportados são apenas Excel, PDF, Word e Imagem pois não é extensível.